# Installing cryptography using pip on Raspbian Jessie image

Tags: python, raspbian-jessie, pip

I am trying to get `netmiko` (which uses `paramiko`) installed on Raspbian Jessie so that I can script SSH commands from my Pi.  It doesn't seem to be that `netmiko` works out-of-the-box as I had hoped.  So here I am.

The `cryptography` library is a requirement and this is what I am struggling with. From a fresh Jessie image I went and run the following from the terminal in sequence:

```
# sudo apt-get update
# sudo apt-get upgrade
# sudo apt-get install gcc libffi-dev libssl-dev python-dev
# sudo pip install cryptography
```

Everything installs ok, however the last command returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    import packaging.version
ImportError: No module named packaging.version
```

When I now run `# pip` on its own I get the following returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    import packaging.version
ImportError: No module named packaging.version
```

I have been through the commands I run and pip works at every stage before the install cryptography command.  It's like the cryptography install script broke pip.

Any help would be appreciated.  I am new to Python and Linux.

Comment: Looks like a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-pip/+bug/1658844). There are a couple of suggested approaches [here](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/937) and in the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-pip/+bug/1658844).

Comment: From your link I found instructions to re-install pip using the get-pip.py script downloaded from here
[https://packaging.python.org/installing/#install-pip-setuptools-and-wheel](https://packaging.python.org/installing/#install-pip-setuptools-and-wheel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-installing pip seems to have fixed it.  Thanks to goobering's link in his comment.

I downloaded get-pip.py from [this section of the python website](https://packaging.python.org/installing/#install-pip-setuptools-and-wheel), then from terminal run `sudo python get-pip.py`.

Since pip is now working I then run `sudo pip install netmiko` and tested from Python: `from netmiko import ConnectHandler`

Full list of commands to get netmiko working on fresh Raspbian Jessy image:

```
# sudo apt-get update
# sudo apt-get upgrade
# sudo apt-get install gcc libffi-dev libssl-dev python-dev
# sudo pip install cryptography
# wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
# sudo python get-pip.py
# sudo pip install netmiko
```

Comment: Can confirm netmiko is "talking" to my Cisco 1921 router.

Answer (score 2):

I found the following commands were sufficient to fix my Raspbian Jessie install where Kodi was giving an error message about the old version of Python Cryptography.

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get upgrade  
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev libssl-dev python-dev  
sudo pip install setuptools  
sudo pip install cryptography
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the follow above suggest commands to fix my Raspbian Jessy install of Kodi's error message on the Python Cryptography version error.  I used this suggested Full list of commands to get netmiko working on fresh Raspbian Jessy image:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install gcc libffi-dev libssl-dev python-dev
sudo pip install cryptography
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
sudo pip install netmiko
```

But, I got back an error message stating  that I needed an updated setuptools so on trying the last line.
so I found the follow suggested code on another help thread and tried

```
sudo python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

and then

```
sudo pip install netmiko
```

this seemed to allowed netmiko to install
and when I went into kodi I did not get the cryptography error.

Answer (score 0):

if `pip` is not installed, first try `sudo wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`

after that, using `sudo python get-pip.py` install the pip. and then try `sudo pip install netmiko`